# req.body undefined after authenticating with passport jwt strategy

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I am using JWT to do authentication with a user in my express app. One of the routes needs to be authenticated before continuing so I am doing so like this per following the documentation and a tutorial:

```
router.post('/current/update', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),(res, req) => {
  console.log(req.body) //undefined
}
```

**passport.js**

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Account = mongoose.model('accounts')
const keys = require('./keys');

const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey;

module.exports = passport => {
    passport.use(
      new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
          Account.findById(jwt_payload.id)
          .then(account => {
              if(account){
                  return done(null, account)
              }
              return done(null, false)
          }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
              return done(err)
            })
    })
  );
};
```

Not knowing how to get access to the body of the request is troubling because that means I don't know how to get access to the `req.params` and `req.query`. I have tried numerous methods, including passing the `req` along with the strategy:

```
new JwtStrategy(opts, (req, jwt_payload, done) => ...
```

So question is, if not gotten from above, is how do I get access to the `req` object, other than just `req.user`so that I am able to handle parameterized URLs and queries?

Comment: Have you used body-parser?

Comment: Yes that is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the JwtStrategy to pass the `req` object to your callback. You can do this via the options object you supply to the strategy. Your code will look something like this:

```
const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey;
opts.passReqToCallback = true; // New option!
```

Then in your callback function you'll need to also accept the `req` field which comes in as the first argument to the function. So your callback initialisation goes from

```
new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done)
```

and becomes

```
new JwtStrategy(opts, (req, jwt_payload, done)
```

You can then access the full express request object via `req`. As noted in the comments, you'll also need something like `body-parser` to ensure it's decoded properly.

Comment: I am using body parser in the server and I have already tried adding req to the callback as I showed in my original text

Comment: @DallasPhillips as said in my answer, you must add the *new option* `passReqToCallback` to your opts object and set the value to `true`. You've not done this in the code above, and it is why your `req` in the callback is not getting set.

Comment: Well even by doing that I can't access anything from req. Not even user or body, but I can console out the req but again, im not getting access to anything inside it